# Create Read Stream in Node js fetching favicon.ico instead of file

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I'm trying to get the mp3 file located in the **imageDir**  folder using a node server and play the audio file in browser. When tried this using **fs.readFile**, it is working fine. But when doing the same using **fs.createReadStream**, it is not loading the .mp3 file, instead it is loading the favicon.ico in network tab of the console.

Here's the code

```
/******************************** With streams ************************************/
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");[enter image description here][1]

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3'});
    var myreadStream = fs.createReadStream('./imageDir/logosong.mp3', 'utf8');

    myreadStream.pipe(response);



}).listen(3334);
console.log('Listening');
```

[image: Screen shot from console]

Trying to learn node streams. Please explain where I was wrong.